# If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, find $F'(x)$ for the following $F(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$F{x}=\int_{0}^{x \cos(x)}{t f(t)dt}$$

So here is my process/where I am confused:

suppose $\phi(x)=x \cos(x)$ which is continuously differentiable on $[0,x]$ and also $\phi '(x)=\cos(x)-x \sin(x) dx$.

This is where I get confused(Change of Variable):
what happens to the $t$ in front of $f(t)$?:
does the integral become

$$F{(x)}=\int_{0}^{x}{x f(x \cos(x))[\cos(x)-x\sin(x)] dx}$$
or
$$F{(x)}=\int_{0}^{x}{x\cos(x) f(x\cos(x))[\cos(x)-x\sin(x) ]dx}?$$

This is the only part I'm confused on, I know how to continue to the answer by FTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need to use a change of variables, here. let 
$$h(x)= \int_0^x t f(t)\, dt$$
$$g(x) = x\cos(x)$$
Then $F(x) = h(g(x))$, so $F'(x) = g'(x)h'(g(x))$. Noting that $h'(x) = xf(x)$ by the FTOC, we have 
$$F'(x) = (\cos(x) - x\sin(x))\cdot x\cos(x)\cdot f(x\cos(x))$$
So based on this answer, that last integral you have is correct. This is because you're letting $t = u\cos(u)$, and so you substitute that for $t$ everywhere in the integrand. As a side note, you should use something other than $x$ inside the integrand, since $x$ is already representing the bound of the integral.